# How to add two django variables in a django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a object **rec** which I have passed through the dictionary from my view.
I want to concatenate two of its values and pass it to a custom filter that I have designed

The issue I am facing is that I am unable to concatenate two django variables.
Below is the code that I tried.

```
{% with name=rec.category|add:'_'|add:rec.max_saving %}

{{ name }}

{% endwith%}
```

One alternative is that I can concatenate it in the view itself and pass it as separate property of that object. But I was looking for another way as this procedure requires me to append all my objects instead of few specific one's that I require.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Does `{{ name }}` return anything? If you manually try `{{ rec.category }}` and `{{ rec.max_saving}}` do they print anything? The code you supplied should work.

Comment: What are `rec.category` and `rec.max_saving`? Their types matter.

Comment: @rinti - when adding manually it returns an empty string

Comment: @okm - rec.category returns a string 
       amd rec.max_saving returns a integer

Comment: @okm - your question answered my query - turns out the datatype should be the same - thanks a lot for the help

Comment: You're welcome. Then you could for example change `max_saving` to a string in an outer `with` tag: `{% with max_saving_str=rec.max_saving|stringformat:"s" %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{% with saving=rec.max_saving|slugify %}

{% with name=rec.category|add:'_'|add:rec.max_saving %}

{{ name }}

{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}

This issue I was facing was due to the two variables being of different datatype's.
Using slugify i converted the **int** variable to string.

Slugify worked for me because there was no spaces in my max_saving variable.
Ideally one should use **stringformat:"s"** for django styled string conversion.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

`{% with rec.category|add:'_'|add:rec.max_saving as name %}
     {{ name }}
{% endwith %}`

Comment: I tried the same earlier, the issue occurs when concatenating with other django variable
eg - {% rec.category|add:'_'|add:'random text'|add:'random text' as name %} 
the above line works fine

Comment: @gunj_desai what do you mean by other django variables, can you please elaborate...?

Comment: okm answered my query, but just to explain further I was facing an issue while concatenating two django variables rather 
eg - {{ var1}} and {{ var2}}
Turns out the variables have to be of the same datatype